# Undeclared identifier problem when I start to add the resulting condition with if

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
Boll = color.black
if close[0] > high[30] 
    Boll := white
else if close[0] < low[30]
    Boll := blue
else
    Boll := brown

    SqueezeExpand = color.white
if Boll == color.white and Boll1 == color.white and Boll2 == color.white and Boll3 == color.white Boll4 == color.white 
    SqueezeExpand := green
else if Boll == color.blue and Boll1 == color.blue and Boll2 == color.blue and Boll3 == color.blue Boll4 == color.blue    
    SqueezeExpand := red
else 
    SqueezeExpand := color.gray
```

The undeclared identifier starts when I try to make Boll == white/blue/brown in an if condition alongside other conditions.

Comment: What are `Boll1`, `Boll2`, `Boll3` and `Boll4`?

Answer (score 0):

You have pine version issues.

Starting from v4, colors have been moved to `color.*` namespace (e.g. `color.black`, `color.white` etc.). Before that, it was just the color names (e.g. `black`, `white` etc.).

```
Boll = color.black
if close[0] > high[30] 
    Boll := color.white
else if close[0] < low[30]
    Boll := color.blue
else
    Boll := color.brown
```

Comment: It is still undeclared when I try to make the == in  if Boll == color.white and Boll1 == color.green and Boll2 == color. blue etc etc.

Comment: Please share your complete code.

Comment: SqueezeExpand = color.white
    if Boll == color.white and Boll1 == color.white and Boll2 == color.white and Boll3 == color.white Boll4 == color.white 
        SqueezeExpand := green
    else if Boll == color.white and Boll1 == color.white and Boll2 == color.white and Boll3 == color.white Boll4 == color.white    SqueezeExpand := red
    else 
        SqueezeExpand := color.gray

   Boll = color.black
if close[0] > high[30] 
    Boll := color.white
else if close[0] < low[30]
    Boll := color.blue
else
    Boll := color.brown

Comment: I added an edit in my original OP.